# Who is the goddess Kalavikarnika?

Tags: identification-request, goddess, reference-request, disease

There seems to be a goddess with the name of Kalavikarnika. I can find a few mentions of her online, most of which recycle the same few facts over and over. There is a similar-sounding goddess in [this short article from Hindu-Blog](https://www.hindu-blog.com/2022/01/goddess-kalavikarni-about-hindu-kalavikarnika.html), and she is included in [this encyclopedia](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionary_of_Gods_and_Goddesses/aqDC5bwx4_wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Kalavikarnika) of gods and goddesses from across the world. It says that she is a Puranic goddess associated with fevers and healing and that some of her artifacts include a cup/skull. Other sources claim that she has blueish skin and that the cup that she drinks from is in fact a skull.

Yet for all that, I cannot find a single mention of her in any canonical text (Purana/Veda/Itihasa), and there don't seem to be any actual stories about her.

- *Are* there any mentions of a goddess named Kalavikarnika in an actual Hindu text?
- Are the details provided by the other sources above in fact accurate? (she cures fevers, has blue skin, drinks from a skull, etc.)
- Are there any other details about her?

([Related](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/goddesses-with-skull-cup-in-one-hand): if anyone can find an answer to this question, they can probably add an answer to the other one, too.)